# Why this code is generating error C2105 instead of C3892?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, lvalue

> IDE: MS Visual studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM
>
> Compiler: Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version
> 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86

Code:

```
// main.cpp - compiled as cpp file
int main()
{
 const int x = 10;
 x++; // error C2105: '++' needs l-value
 x = x+1; // error C3892: 'x' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
 return(0);
}
```

What `l-value` is compiler expecting to throw error C2105?

Comment: Because they are semantically 2 different operations?

Comment: @Abhineet: Better, thanks. Have posted a new answer to the clarified question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`x` *is* an lvalue, so the diagnostic message is misleading.**

This is a quality of implementation issue, i.e. a bug.

Whatever routine that detects the `const` is mangled up with the routine that checks for the expression `x` in your `x++` not being an rvalue.

The end result is the same! So it's unlikely that anyone hugely cares. You *could* raise this issue on Microsoft Connect and see whether it goes anywhere, but you should probably test your code on newer versions first, since 2008 was rather a long time ago.

For what it's worth, I get the same result in Visual Studio 2012 Express; Intellisense clarifies that it's a "*modifiable* lvalue" that it's hoping for:

[image: Screenshot of the result in VS2012]

Comment: Wow...ain't you quick :)

Comment: You are going epic. I can't control my laugh.

Comment: FWIW 2015 does that same thing but it puts the intelliSense errors next to the relevant compiler errors.